# OCaml, PLplot, get rid of the prompt

Tags: plot, output, ocaml

When I use the "native" PLplot in OCaml (i.e. just calling plinit ()), I have the following output in the terminal :

```
Plotting Options:
 < 1> ps         PostScript File (monochrome)
 < 2> psc        PostScript File (color)
 < 3> xfig       Fig file
 < 4> null       Null device
 < 5> mem        User-supplied memory device
 < 6> wxwidgets  wxWidgets Driver
 < 7> svg        Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG 1.1)
 < 8> bmpqt      Qt Windows bitmap driver
 < 9> jpgqt      Qt jpg driver
 <10> pngqt      Qt png driver
 <11> ppmqt      Qt ppm driver
 <12> tiffqt     Qt tiff driver
 <13> svgqt      Qt SVG driver
 <14> qtwidget   Qt Widget
 <15> epsqt      Qt EPS driver
 <16> pdfqt      Qt PDF driver
 <17> extqt      External Qt driver
 <18> memqt      Memory Qt driver
```

However, when I use :

```
module P = Plot

p = P.init (0., 0.) 
    (max_length, max_length) 
    `greedy 
    (`svg `core)
    ~filename:("myfile.svg");
```

I can output my graph to an external file.

The problem is that most of the three dimensional plots cannot be called from the "module P". I have a large number of graphs to generate and answering the prompts becomes the bottleneck...

Is there a way to have PLplot output the graphs into a file directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the device (`plsdev`) and filename if it's a file-backed device (`plsfnam`) before calling `plinit` to avoid the prompts.